# Retrieve wrong DateTime

Tags: powershell, datetime, event-log

I'm using this code below to retrieve the value for the `TimeGenerated` on a win32 event log on a remote server.

```
$event = Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $server -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE LogFile='Application' AND CategoryString = 'Server Startup'" |
         Select  -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated -First 1
```

The return value is:

```
20160123155933.000000-000
```

but the event log via the event viewer shows this as the value:

```
Logged: 1/23/2016 10:59:33 AM
```

How would I extract the correct date in the format above?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, if you run your command in the ISE, you can discover properties and commands on the objects returned using IntelliSense.

That said, [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/01/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-read-from-windows-event-logs-with-windows-powershell-2-0.aspx) talks a lot about "eventlog" and "TimeGenerated" (the 2 terms I searched on the find this answer).

Don't use `-ExpandProperty`, but rather call `ConvertToDateTime()` something similar to what I show below (I modified your call to just grab the first event in my log).

```
$obj = Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE LogFile='Application'" | Select -First 1 
$obj.ConvertToDateTime($obj.TimeGenerated).ToString()
```

This outputs a formatted date converted from *raw* UTC to local time.

```
TimeGenerated    : 20160124010615.134877-000
```

becomes

```
1/23/2016 5:06:15 PM
```

I think with this info, you have a workable solution to build upon.